# How to disable the pinned header feture on the Sticky grid view in android

Tags: android, android-gridview

**What i am trying to do** :: 
I want header for a certain set of rows one after another

**What i am using**:: [**`Sticky Header`**](http://tonicartos.github.io/StickyGridHeaders/)( i am running [this](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/zipball/master) sample)

**What is happening**:: 
Project runs well but when i scroll the header goes and sits on top until the next header comes

**Question**:: (Disabling pinned header & enable the header scroll along with grid)

- I want to disable this feature so that the header scrolls along with
  gridview being scrolled instead of waiting for the next header
- I have seen this feature possible in expandable listview but how to
  implement this here

---

**ItemDetailFragment.java**

```
public class ItemDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
     * represents.
     */
    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

    /**
     * The dummy content this fragment is presenting.
     */
    private int mItem;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public ItemDetailFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
            // Load the dummy content specified by the fragment
            // arguments. In a real-world scenario, use a Loader
            // to load content from a content provider.
            mItem = getArguments().getInt(ARG_ITEM_ID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail, container, false);

        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail)).setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries)[mItem]);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**ItemListActivity.java**

```
public class ItemListActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ItemListFragment.Callbacks {
    /**
     * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
     * device.
     */
    private boolean mTwoPane;

    /**
     * Callback method from {@link ItemListFragment.Callbacks} indicating that
     * the item with the given ID was selected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(int id) {
        if (mTwoPane) {
            // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
            // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
            // fragment transaction.
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putInt(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
            .commit();
        } else {
            // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
            // for the selected item ID.
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
            detailIntent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

        if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
            // The detail container view will be present only in the
            // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
            // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
            // activity should be in two-pane mode.
            mTwoPane = true;

            // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
            // 'activated' state when touched.
            ((ItemListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.item_list)).setActivateOnItemClick(true);
        }
        // TODO: If exposing deep links into your app, handle intents here.
    }
}
```

**ItemListFragment.java**

```
public class ItemListFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener,
        OnHeaderClickListener, OnHeaderLongClickListener {
    private static final String KEY_LIST_POSITION = "key_list_position";

    /**
     * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
     * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
     */
    private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(int id) {
        }
    };

    /**
     * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
     * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
     */
    private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";
    /**
     * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
     */
    private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
    /**
     * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
     * clicks.
     */
    private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

    private int mFirstVisible;

    private GridView mGridView;

    private Menu mMenu;

    private Toast mToast;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public ItemListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
        if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
        }

        mCallbacks = (Callbacks)activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_item_list, menu);
        mMenu = menu;
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_toggle_sticky).setChecked(
                ((StickyGridHeadersGridView)mGridView).areHeadersSticky());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_grid, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
        mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public void onHeaderClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, long id) {
        String text = "Header " + ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getText() + " was tapped.";
        if (mToast == null) {
            mToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } else {
            mToast.setText(text);
        }
        mToast.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onHeaderLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, long id) {
        String text = "Header " + ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getText() + " was long pressed.";
        if (mToast == null) {
            mToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } else {
            mToast.setText(text);
        }
        mToast.show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> gridView, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_toggle_sticky:
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                ((StickyGridHeadersGridView)mGridView)
                        .setAreHeadersSticky(!((StickyGridHeadersGridView)mGridView)
                                .areHeadersSticky());

                return true;
            case R.id.menu_use_list_adapter:
                mGridView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries)));
                mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_use_list_adapter).setVisible(false);
                mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_use_sticky_adapter).setVisible(true);
                mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_toggle_sticky).setVisible(false);
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_use_sticky_adapter:
                mGridView.setAdapter(new StickyGridHeadersSimpleArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext(), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries),
                        R.layout.header, R.layout.item));
                mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_use_list_adapter).setVisible(true);
                mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_toggle_sticky).setVisible(true);
                mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_use_sticky_adapter).setVisible(false);
                return true;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
            outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mGridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.asset_grid);
        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        /*
         * Currently set in the XML layout, but this is how you would do it in
         * your code.
         */
        // mGridView.setColumnWidth((int) calculatePixelsFromDips(100));
        // mGridView.setNumColumns(StickyGridHeadersGridView.AUTO_FIT);
        mGridView.setAdapter(new StickyGridHeadersSimpleArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext(), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries),
                R.layout.header, R.layout.item));

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mFirstVisible = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_LIST_POSITION);
        }

        mGridView.setSelection(mFirstVisible);

        // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
            setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
        }

        ((StickyGridHeadersGridView)mGridView).setOnHeaderClickListener(this);
        ((StickyGridHeadersGridView)mGridView).setOnHeaderLongClickListener(this);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    /**
     * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
     * given the 'activated' state when touched.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
        // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
        // give items the 'activated' state when touched.

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            mGridView.setChoiceMode(activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                    : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
        if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            mGridView.setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
        } else {
            mGridView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }

        mActivatedPosition = position;
    }

    /**
     * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
     * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
     * selections.
     */
    public interface Callbacks {
        /**
         * Callback for when an item has been selected.
         */
        public void onItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

**ItemDetailActivity.java**

```
public class ItemDetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
                // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
                // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
                // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
                //
                // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
                //
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, ItemListActivity.class));
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_detail);

        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // savedInstanceState is non-null when there is fragment state
        // saved from previous configurations of this activity
        // (e.g. when rotating the screen from portrait to landscape).
        // In this case, the fragment will automatically be re-added
        // to its container so we don't need to manually add it.
        // For more information, see the Fragments API guide at:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
        //
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Create the detail fragment and add it to the activity
            // using a fragment transaction.
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putInt(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID,
                    getIntent().getIntExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, 0));
            ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the headers scroll with your view by adding the following to your code:

`mGridView.setAreHeadersSticky(false);`

Hope this helps.